# Block editor layout not present in post editor

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

I have a WordPress block theme entirely built using the block editor, i.e. empty html template files. Since a recent update of WordPress, the post editor is not abiding to the width applied in the theme editor. In the theme editor (Code editor) I can see that "layout":`{"type":"constrained","contentSize":"1135px"}` is present and working correctly, however in the post editor, the class `is-layout-flow` has been applied, rather than `is-layout-constrained`. What am I missing?

I have cleared the browser, and website cache, re-saved the theme, and disabled all plugins.